# Changing hightlighting color for MatchTag plugin in Vim

Tags: html, vim

Recently I installed this awesome HTML [plugin](https://github.com/gregsexton/MatchTag), which matches closing tags, and it works really well. I was just wondering if it's possible to change highlighting color (I'm using [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) colorscheme). Here's screenshot of how it looks now:

[image]

I think it's possible to change the color in solarized.vim file, but there's a lot of highlighting options. I would like to set it to some other color, that's more pleasant for the eye, as tags are barely seen because of low contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MatchTag plugin is using the related `MatchParen` *highlight group* (`:help hl-MatchParen`). You can relink that to any other group in your `~/.vimrc`, for example:

```
:hi link MatchParen IncSearch
```

or define your own highlight attributes. Put the command *after* any `:colorscheme` command, though.

Comment: `:hi link MatchParen IncSearch` didn't work for me when I added it to .vimrc file, so I modified MatchTagAlways.vim file directly and set `s:set_match_group = 'IncSearch'`. Now it highlights tags exactly as incremental search does. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help, but the MatchTag plugin you linked to doesn't contain a MatchTagAlways.vim and no `s:set_match_group` variable. You probably meant [this](https://github.com/Valloric/MatchTagAlways).

Comment: And for that, you don't need to modify the script itself, you can configure that, too (even have several alternative options!) Read [here](https://github.com/Valloric/MatchTagAlways#the-gmta_use_matchparen_group-option).

Comment: Thanks, that makes even more sense! The problem is is that I didn't know what `MatchParen` group was at the beginning, that's why I never paid attention to those options.